# How to get Excel Row as 1D object array into VB.net

Tags: arrays, excel, vb.net

I am trying to pull a row of data from an excel spreadsheet that I already have open, in order to compare it with an existing 1D array of values. As far as I can tell, when I try to pull a range such as

```
Dim excelArray(49) as object
excelArray = sheet1.Range("B3", "AY3").Value
```

it returns a 2d array, even though it only has a single row. This line in my code errors because of this. I need it to compare with another array that is already populated which is actually an array of Singles. The above excel row also contains a row of singles in each cell.

```
Dim otherArray(49) as object
```

Is there a way to do this that does not involve the following.

```
    For i As Integer = 2 To 51
        indexJ = i - 2
        excelArray(indexJ) = sheet1.Cells(3, j).value
    Next j
```

I do not wish to do it the above way because I am doing this with several large arrays, multiple times. The process of doing it cell by cell seems to be taking a long time.

Comment: `ReDim` and `Preserve`?

Comment: Just include the second dimension, even though it will always be **1** as in `excelarray(indexJ, 1)`

Comment: @PeterT but how would I then compare the two arrays? one would be 1 dimension, the other would be 2. And ultimately I will need this array to be 1 later.

Comment: Use `If excelarray(indexJ, 1) = otherArray(indexJ) Then ...` inside the loop

Comment: @PeterT but I later need to send a 1D array back to a opc server from the excel data. And I don't think there is an easy way to convert the VB.net 2d arrays to 1d without looping, and that is what I was trying to avoid in the first place.

Comment: The only way to get your days into a 1D array will be a loop unfortunately.

Comment: bummer. They really should have the functionality of pulling out a 1D array if there are no columns. I was surprised that rows() did not